# jekyll website not updating on github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I recently played around with the Jekyll/Poole/Lanyon theme for a new blog. At first, I linked my domain jonathancharleslee.com to my github pages site at jonathancharleslee.github.io

When I update files locally, I can update site features and posts - however, when I push to github it won't update on jonathancharleslee.github.io

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note, you can automate the process by using Travis: http://wouterj.nl/2015/02/using-travis-to-build-your-sculpin-blog/ (applies both to Sculpin and Jekyll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a user/organisation repository (username.github.io). This type of repository needs you to push in master branch, **not** in gh-pages.

See [Github Pages doc](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be working and making all your changes on the `development` branch, then pushing ONLY your built files to the `master` branch, which is what Github Pages will publish.

There's step-by-step instructions on how to do this in this posting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296933/7669275